# Translating warning codes as messages to be printed

Tags: c

I am writing an X application with Xlib in C, and this code is for error handling and error printing.

How to make it simpler and clearer **without using a large amount of `fprintf`**?

```
int XB3DS_Warn_Code (int Warn_Code)
{
  switch(Warn_Code)
  {
    case WARN_Failed_To_Connect_To_Display:
      fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: Failed to connect to display.\n");
      break;
    case WARN_Width_Or_Height_Is_Unacceptable:
      fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: Width or height is unacceptable.\n");
      break;
    case WARN_No_Visual_Is_Matched_For_Screen:
      fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: No visual is matched for screen.\n");
      break;
    case WARN_The_Window_Mode_Is_Unacceptable:
      fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: The window mode is unacceptable.\n");
      break;
    case WARN_Insufficient_Memory_To_Allocate:
      fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: Insufficient memory to allocate.\n");
      break;
  }
  return Warn_Code;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the variable part of the message in a variable, and do the printing after the `switch`, for example:

```
int XB3DS_Warn_Code (int Warn_Code)
{
  const char * msg;
  switch(Warn_Code)
  {
    case WARN_Failed_To_Connect_To_Display:
      msg = "Failed to connect to display.";
      break;
    case WARN_Width_Or_Height_Is_Unacceptable:
      msg = "Width or height is unacceptable.";
      break;
    case WARN_No_Visual_Is_Matched_For_Screen:
      msg = "No visual is matched for screen.";
      break;
    case WARN_The_Window_Mode_Is_Unacceptable:
      msg = "The window mode is unacceptable.";
      break;
    case WARN_Insufficient_Memory_To_Allocate:
      msg = "Insufficient memory to allocate.";
      break;
    default:
      msg = "Unknown error.";
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: %s\n", msg);
  return Warn_Code;
}
```

Now the `case` statements only have the absolutely necessary code. It's the most basic kind of refactoring: extracting values to variables and filling them in a template later. Another variant would be extracting common logic to a helper function. I also added a `default` case that was missing: it's always good to have.

Also, instead of `fprintf(stdout, ...)` why not use simply `printf(...)` ?

Finally, as [@black](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37137/black) pointed out, *"What's the point to return what you get passed?"* Better change the method signature to return `void`. Even better, return the message instead of printing, so that the rest of your code can do whatever it needs with it, for example:

```
const char * XB3DS_Get_Warn_Message (int Warn_Code) {
    const char * msg;
    // the switch ...
    return msg;
}

void XB3DS_Handle_Warning (int Warn_Code) {
    const char * msg = XB3DS_Get_Warn_Message(Warn_Code);
    fprintf(stdout, "[  WARNING  ]: %s\n", msg);
}
```

Change the rest of your code to call `XB3DS_Handle_Warning` instead of your current `XB3DS_Warn_Code`. Right now you just want to print to `stdout`. But maybe someday you will want to log to a file, or show as part of a GUI. Then you won't need to touch `XB3DS_Get_Warn_Message` anymore, but change the simpler `XB3DS_Handle_Warning` helper.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help. For the question you asked, I chose `fprintf` instead of `printf` because of consistency. (I use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` for printing fatal error messages)

Comment: What's the point to return what you get passed? Return a `const char *`.

Comment: Good point! I overlooked that. I updated my post, and also changed the type of `msg` to `const char *`. Thanks @black!

Comment: You're welcome @janos. But I meant something more like: `const char *XB3DS_Warn_Code (int Warn_Code)` and you simply return `msg`. The user will then decide how to handle that message.

Comment: @black Right you are again. I amended my post.

Answer (score 2):

The messages should be stored in an array.  Then the problem becomes a simple array lookup.

Furthermore, you need to split the translation aspect of your function from the printing aspect.  Someday, you might want to do something other than print the message to `stdout`, and then your function would be useless.

#### `xb3ds_err.h`

```
#include <stddef.h>

char *XB3DS_Warnings[] =
{
#define WARN_OK 0
    "",
#define WARN_Failed_To_Connect_To_Display 1
    "Failed to connect to display",
#define WARN_Width_Or_Height_Is_Unacceptable 2
    "Width or height is unacceptable",
#define WARN_No_Visual_Is_Matched_For_Screen 3
    "No visual is matched for screen",
#define WARN_The_Window_Mode_Is_Unacceptable 4
    "The window mode is unacceptable",
#define WARN_Insufficient_Memory_To_Allocate 5
    "Insufficient memory to allocate",
    NULL
};

const char *XB3DS_Warn_Msg(int Warn_Code);
```

#### `xb3ds_err.c`

```
#include "xb3ds_err.h"

const char *XB3DS_Warn_Msg(int Warn_Code)
{   
    return XB3DS_Warnings[Warn_Code];
}
```

#### In your application

```
#include "xb3ds_err.h"

…

printf("[ WARNiNG ]: %s.\n", XB3DS_Warn_Msg(Warn_Code));
```